# PHP cURL - How to check if Google Crawler gets the correct robots.txt

Tags: php, curl

Google somehow started to index the https version of my website. To stop this I read a tutorial which said I need 2 different robots.txt files and some addtional code in the .htaccess

.htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^robots\.txt$ robots-https.txt
```

robots-https.txt

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

Some days now have past and Google still hasn't started to deindex the https-pages.
So now I'am a little bit worried and want to test if the changes are done correctly.

Is there a way with PHP & cURL to check which robots.txt is being used in a https connection?

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: You may need to contact Google via their webmaster tools and ask them to de-index.  You will probably also need to set the appropriate robots meta tags in the https versions of your pages.

Comment: The webmaster tools doesn't offer the possibility to check the robots.txt for https. But you're right with the meta tags. Next step is to add the canonical tag.

Answer (score 0):

If you're serving the two versions of the site from different document roots, then simply keep two copies of the robots.txt:

```
/home/sites/example.com/http/robots.txt
/home/sites/example.com/https/robots.txt
```

if they're both coming from the same physical directory, then you can simply use an Apache alias in the virtualhost definitions:

```
<virtualhost example.com:443>
   Alias /robots.txt  /physical/path/to/ssl/robots.txt
</virtualhost>

<virtualhost example.com:80>
   Alias /robots.txt /path/to/standard/robots.txt
</virtualhost>
```

with no need to resort to regexes and mod_rewrite.

Comment: Seems also to be a good solution, but in this case I can't access the server conf, because I'am using some cheap webspace :/